# plan: plano vs. plan

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario

The English "plan" can be translated into Spanish as *plan* or *plano*. What is the difference between *plan* and *plano*, and when would each one be used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's look at what Webster says about *plan*:
Definition of PLAN

> plan
>
> 1. : a drawing or diagram drawn on a plane: as
>    a : a top or horizontal view of an object
>    b : a large-scale map of a small area
> 2. a : a method for achieving an end
>    b : an often customary method of doing something : procedure
>    c : a detailed formulation of a program of action
>    d : goal, aim
> 3. : an orderly arrangement of parts of an overall design or objective
> 4. : a detailed program (as for payment or the provision of
>    some service)

Now, let's look at what RAE says for *plano* and *plan*:

> plano, na.
> (Del lat. planus).
> 4. m. Representación esquemática, en dos dimensiones y a determinada escala, de un terreno, una población, una máquina, una construcción, etc.
>
> plan.   (De plano).
> 2. m. Intención, proyecto.
> 3. m. Modelo sistemático de una actuación pública o privada, que se elabora anticipadamente para dirigirla y encauzarla.
> 4. m. Escrito en que sumariamente se precisan los detalles para realizar una obra.
> 5. m. Dieta, régimen de vida, especialmente alimenticio. El plan que siguió fue muy severo.

Summarizing, **plan translates as**:

- plano, when it is used in it definition 1 (and sometimes 3): a diagram, a map...
- plan, when it is used in its definitions 2 and 4 (and sometimes 3): a program of action, a goal...

**Some examples**:

- plano de Barcelona
- plano del metro
- plano de una casa (a floorplan)
- plan de acción
- plan de pensiones
- ¡Tengo un plan! (I have an idea of a set of steps to achieve a goal)
- ¡Tengo un plano! (I have a map or schematic drawing)